# Flickr API, JSON request using jquery Infinitescroll, how to know when last page is loaded?

Tags: jquery, json, image, flickr, infinite-scroll

I am trying to get photos from Flickr using jquery infinitescroll. My code is working well to load photos but my issue is the code to know that the last page has been reached. My current code keeps trying to load pages beyond what is available, although no photos are loaded. Here is my flickr  and inifinitescroll code. Any help would be appreciated! I am too much of a newbie to know how to deal with currentPage++; knowing it has reached the last page.

```
function ajaxProcess() {

var searchTerm = $("#term").val(); // get the user-entered search term
var URL2='http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.people.getPublicPhotos&user_id=57333193@N00&api_key=f290d9d56bd82fde0c87d7fd6a0e6c33&'; 
var tags="&tags="+ searchTerm;
var tagmode="&tagmode=any";
var jsonFormat = "&format=json";                    
var ajaxURL= URL2+"per_page="+perpage+"&page="+currentPage+tags+tagmode+jsonFormat;
                //var ajaxURL= URL+"?"+tags+tagmode+jsonFormat;

             $.ajax({
              url:ajaxURL,
              dataType:"jsonp",
              jsonp:"jsoncallback",
              success: function(data) {
                   // $("#photos").empty(); 
                    if(data.stat!="fail") {
                         console.log(data); 
                        //$("#photos").empty();
                        // $("figure").empty();
    $.each(data.photos.photo,   function(i,photo) {
  var photoHTML="";
 photoHTML+=" <a href='";                                   photoHTML+="http://farm"+photo.farm+".static.flickr.com/"+photo.server+"/"+photo.id+"_"+photo.secret+"_b.jpg'";
photoHTML+=">";  
photoHTML+= "<figure class=\"effeckt-caption\" data-effeckt-type=\"quarter-zoom\"> <img class=\"img-rounded\" src='";                             photoHTML+="http://farm"+photo.farm+".static.flickr.com/"+photo.server+"/"+photo.id+"_"+photo.secret+"_q.jpg'"; 
photoHTML+=" title='"+photo.title+"'" ;
photoHTML+=" >" ;
photoHTML+="<figcaption class=\"caption\"><div class=\"effeckt-figcaption-wrap\"" ;                            photoHTML+=">'"+photo.title+"'</div></figcaption></figure></a>";
                              $("#gallery").append(photoHTML).fadeIn(400);                                                        
});

}else {
$("#gallery").empty();
console.log("Error code "+data.stat);
photoHTML="Error !! Error !! "+data.stat;


}

}
});

}
 var perpage=30;
 var currentPage=1;

$('#gallery').infinitescroll({
    navSelector     : "a#next",
    nextSelector    : "a#next",
    itemSelector    : "#gallery a",
    debug           : true,
    dataType        : "json",
    speed: 'fast',
    animate: true,
    loading: {
            finishedMsg: "All Images Loaded",
            img: "res/icons/load.gif",
            msgText: "<em>Adding More Images...</em>"
},
    prefill         : true,
    behavior        : "twitter",
    errorCallback: function() {
  // fade out the error message after 2.5 seconds
  $('#infscr-loading').animate({opacity: 0.8},2500).fadeOut('normal');
   $('a#next').addClass('disabled');
}

}, function(json, opts) {
    ajaxProcess();
    currentPage++;

});
   $( "a#next" ).on( "click", function() {
            ajaxProcess();
    currentPage++;
    });
```

Comment: can you also include the code where you set up the infinite scroll?

Comment: It is there if you scroll down

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the simplest way is to check use the plugin's `pause` method once you've detected that the json returned from Flickr is empty. This can be done via your ajax success callback:

```
....
$.ajax({
    url:ajaxURL,
    dataType:"jsonp",
    jsonp:"jsoncallback",
    success: function(data) {
        if(data.stat != "fail") {
            if (data.photos.photo.length === 0) {
                // pause infiniate scroll if empty
                $('#gallery').infinitescroll('pause');
            }
            $.each(data.photos.photo, function(i,photo) {
                // ... 
            });

        } else {
            $("#gallery").empty();
            console.log("Error code "+data.stat);
            photoHTML="Error !! Error !! "+data.stat;
        }
    }
});
....
```

Notice there's a new condition after you've checked whether the call failed or not; in my example I simply check whether the array of photos is empty and if so call tell infinite scroll to pause.

This will still result in an extra call in most cases so you could also consider checking whether the array of photos is less that the per_page value too as that would indicate that you've reached the end of the photo stream.